# Зачем создавать програмно, если есть дизайнер форм?

Tags: c#, winforms

Прошу внести ясность. Я начал изучение с# с консоли что не удивительно.

И вот я хочу создать приложение, с неким функционалом в WinForm. Я создаю проект и поехали... Перетащил нужные элементы, заполнил нужные события,  Ну и там реализовал какую-то логику. Все работает, все здорово.

Это вообще нормальная практика? Или нужно учится писать все элементы програмно, и если да, то в чем прелести этого подхода? Чувствую, что я чего-то сильно не понял.

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть список например музыкальных треков (название, кнопка плей, пауза, время и так далее), у вас примерно 1000 треков, будете руками добавлять? А еще они могут (и скорей будут) получаться из другого сервиса и вы не знаете их точное кол-во, как тогда?

Comment: пока вам хватает дизайнера форм - нет никаких проблем с тем, что вы его используете. Используйте те инструменты, что работают для вас. Как только вам дизайнера форм станет мало, вы сами перейдете на ручное создание контролов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас проект с динамическим выводом элементов (не просто скрыть/показать, а именно добавлять разное число элементов в зависимости от полученных данных из базы, аккуратно их распределять по форме - то может пригодиться создание из кода.

В простых проектах обычно достаточно один раз расставить в дизайнере элементы.

Как программист вы должны уметь оба подхода. Начать изучение лучше с визуального.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что это вполне нормальная практика. Главное понимать, как весь этот UI, который Вы используете, транслирует всё это в код. В программной реализации нужда возникает только в каких-то особенных случаях, а так UI всё сделает лучше и красивее, чем человек.

Comment: С первой половиной согласен полностью - понимать что внутри необходимо, для проекта с простым интерфейсом, прототипа или просто  подсмотреть в сгенерированном коде типовые решения вполне подходит. А вот со второй не согласен совсем - динамический контент ни разу не уникальная или особенная задача. По поводу того, что UI сгенерирует в коде тоже масса вопросов, некоторые вещи UI попросту не умеет, генерируется много мусорного кода, но это понимание придет со временем.